# Matplotlib: formatting labels with a specific string pattern

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have following, the x-axis labels in my plot and I want to format it as：`x(x*x*10000)`:

Sample Data

```
0.05   0.10   0.15
```

Expected Output

```
0.05(25)  0.10(100)  0.15(225)
```

is it possible?if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the format of x-ticks and x-labels with `matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`.  Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(0,.3,.05)
y = np.arange(0,.3,.05)

xlabels = ['{0:.2f}({1:.0f})'.format(tick, tick*tick*10000) for tick in x]  

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.xticks(x, xlabels)
plt.show()
```

[image]